# Seeking advice for possible virus

Tags: malware, powershell

I have grown suspicious because I just witnessed powershell opening and immediately closing very fast and multiple times, probably 15 times. After that, the same happened with schtasks.exe. The console again immediately closed and reopened multiple times.

Should I be concerned because of this? What could I do to check for any infection? Antivirus (Avast) doesn't see any problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not tech support. The linked question will provide a range of options for you to try.